# jvm garbage collection too infrequent - clojure

Tags: java, clojure, garbage-collection, jvm

I'm developing a clojure application and it seemed to be using a lot more memory than it should. I thought it was a memory leak but after looking at it with jvisualvm it seems like the GC just isn't running often enough. The red outlines are where I manually invoked the GC. Why is it allocating 300mb when it seems to be using around 30mb?

[image]

Comment: @HotLicks make an answer and I'll accept

Comment: Garbage collection is a large topic. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html

Comment: @noahz -- Yeah, but we try to keep it as small as possible with garbage collection.

Comment: This is a general question about garbage collection, not specific to clojure. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3824215/when-is-garbage-collector-used-in-java Down-voted.

Comment: @noahz How was I supposed to know that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions

Comment: I'll rephrase. I ran into this problem in the context of writing clojure code. Although obvious now, I didn't even think that it might be an inherent property of the JVM. I did search before posting, just not the right things.

Comment: @ilia choly: The JVM need some unused memory in order to run fast (rather than spend all the time by GC). IMHO the more, the better, but 300 MB does hardly bring measurably more than e.g. 60 MB.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make your heap smaller, if you think it's too big. GC only runs when it has to.

(The controls have changed over the years, but I think they're still in terms of an initial heap size, an increment size, and a max size. If your initial heap size is small, it will stay small so long as there's no "high water mark" in heap usage that pushes it higher.)

Answer (score 5):

The JVM has parameters that regulate memory management, including amount initially allocated and max amount to allocate. Other than these parameters, the JVM has no way to know what you consider a reasonable amount of memory to use. To the best of my knowledge, there is no requirement for a JVM to run GC on any particular schedule, nor is any targetted amount of memory usage part of the definition of Java.

Suppose you've said that the max memory available to the JVM is, say, 100 MB, and you are presently using 50 MB including dead objects. You have a NEW that will require 1 MB. Should the JVM run a GC? It's not essential: you have plenty of room before you hit the maxium. Is it a good idea? That's very hard to say. Which is worse, to use a lot of memory or to do a lot of GCs?

As a Java programmer, you shouldn't normally know or care. As long as it does a GC before declaring that you are out of memory, what difference does it make? If your app is using so much memory that other apps can't allocate what they need, than alter the runtime parameters to reduce the maximum that you will take. That should be the limit of what matters.

Answer (score 4):

The JVM uses a generational garbage collector. If you typically have ~30MB of stuff live at any given time, maybe you should set your *new generation* size to something like 60MB. That way the garbage collector should collect all the stuff from your previous pass before they get promoted to the older generation (which gets collected much less frequently).

There are a large set of [performance tuning options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html#PerformanceTuning) for the Sun/Oracle JVM. You probably want to set `-XX:NewSize=60m` for this.

I could be wrong about which option you want to set—there might be one that is much more suitable for this problem. However, I think tweaking with these GC flags is a much better option than just cutting back your total heap size as suggested in the other answers.

***Update:*** Here's some more info I found on the topic of setting generation-specific heap sizes:

[Tuning JVMs: Specifying Heap Size Values](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/perform/JVMTuning.html#1109778)